# I can't able to print the following pyramid in oracle. (PL/SQL Block)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to print the following pyramid:-

```
 ORACLE
 ORACL
 ORAC
 ORA
 OR
 O
```

Comment: I think you missed line 4: "ORA"?

Comment: @kfinity, Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this using a With expression and a LEVEL connector

```
with str as (select 'ORACLE' as str 
               from dual
            )
select substr(s.str, 1, length(s.str)+1 - level) as Pyramid
  from str s
 connect by level-(length(s.str)-1) <= (length(s.str)+1) - level   
  ;
```

also if you needed as PL/SQL block, then solution is:

```
set serveroutput on
declare v_pyramid varchar2(100);
begin 
  with str as (select 'ORACLE' as str from dual)
   select listagg(t.Pyramid, chr(13)) within group (order by t.lvl) 
     into v_pyramid
     from ( select substr(s.str, 1, length(s.str)+1 - level) as Pyramid
                 , level as lvl
              from str s
           connect by level-(length(s.str)-1) <= (length(s.str)+1) - level   
          ) t ;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_pyramid); 
end;
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat shorter code than previous answers:

```
SQL> select substr('ORACLE', 1, level) val
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= length('ORACLE')
  4  order by level desc;

VAL
------------------------
ORACLE
ORACL
ORAC
ORA
OR
O

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Well, it depends on who is looking at it, @Prem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option if you just want plain PL/SQL.

```
declare
  v_str varchar2(6) := 'ORACLE';
begin
  for i in 0 .. length(v_str) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(substr(v_str, 1, length(v_str)-i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is Simple code:-**

```
DECLARE
VAL VARCHAR2(200):='ORACLE';
OT VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    FOR I IN REVERSE 1..LENGTH(VAL) LOOP
        OT:=SUBSTR(VAL,1,I);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OT);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Reverse loop is a nice approach. To simplify it even more you could lose the variable and print the `substr()` expression directly.